# Scroll a div over top of a div above

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replicate an effect seen on this page: http://www.falve.co.nz/collection/

As you scroll the page the white section beneath the darker hero section scrolls over the top of the top hero section, like a curtain.

How do I replicate this? Is this a jQuery thing or CSS position thing? Really unsure how to approach this?

Comment: jQuery to the rescue! Just take the `.scrollTop()` position of the document to mathmatically re-arrange the others in a smooth fashion.

Comment: @CP510 I'm not after the fading in or out just the scroll movement of the bottom section scrolling above the top section. Any ideas how I might do this exactly?

Answer (score 2):

That is called a *[parallax effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax)* and it achieved through javascript.

Here are a [few resources](http://www.desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html) you can use for your own projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position:fixed` and `position : absolute`, you can create the effect with the content pass above the image background. After there are some jquery effects to manage the `fadeOut()` of the text when you catch the scroll event.

```
<body>
    <div id="top">
    </div>
    <div id="content">   
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#top{
    position:fixed;
    height : 200px;
    width : 100%;
    background-image:url("http://www.falve.co.nz/site/uploads/2012/09/1500x900-collection-page-image.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    z-index:1;
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    height : 2000px;
    margin-top:200px;
    width : 100%;
    background-color:#F99;
    z-index:2;
}
```

You have this example on http://jsfiddle.net/UVWdg/

Comment: Could you share any sort of code example to get me started? I'd prefer this to using jQuery

Comment: Try with this plug in : http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/parallax/

Comment: I have add an example to begin development.